# Зачем IDE говорит о вводе временной переменной?

Tags: python, pycharm

Зачем IDE выделяет генератор?

```
res = 1
[res := res * int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(res)
```

и говорит, что его надо оформлять вот так:

```
res = 1
var = [res := res * int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(res)
```

UPD (ответ-вопрос на комментарии):

Ок. Если PyCharm недоволен, что я использую списковое сокращение, тогда почему он во это пропускает:

```
def demo_func(x):
    return x
[demo_func(i) for i in range(10)]
```

А это уже нет:

```
[i for i in range(10)]
```

Как по мне - он должен тогда либо второй вариант не подчеркивать, либо тогда и 1ый блокировать...

UPD 2:

Получается какая-то дискриминация кода программиста, ведь IDE не выделяет такую запись:

```
map(int, input().split())
```

UPD 3:

Сделал замеры (5 раз) и через for получается работает быстрее:

```
[res := res * int(i) for i in [j for j in range(1000000)]]
```

Его итоги:

```
time work: 0:00:00.265001
time work: 0:00:00.218998
time work: 0:00:00.246997
time work: 0:00:00.237997
time work: 0:00:00.253999
```

Против такого:

```
for i in [j for j in range(1000000)]:
    res *= i
```

Его итоги:

```
time work: 0:00:00.180997
time work: 0:00:00.190002
time work: 0:00:00.163006
time work: 0:00:00.156005
time work: 0:00:00.169000
```

UPD 4:

Скрин, от IDE:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD 5:
Скрин то, что хочет видеть IDE:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142650/discussion-on-question-by---ide-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Алексей Ну как вам уже сказали первая и основная проблема это то что вы не используете результат работы своего творения. Я как то задал вопрос по c++ (У меня с ним туго), так вот мой код в плане синтаксиса был правильный но компилятор ругался на какую то фигню. Ответ на мой вопрос был такой - вы до того закрутили голову компилятору что он уже сам не знает что говорит. Так и у вас, есть ведь PEP-стандарт и вы должны его придерживаться.